# Access Array value of side scope in Java

Tags: java, java-ws

I want to know how to return all values of a array variable which are assigned in for loop.

In the method below, I am assigning values to an Output array. Now I want to display all the value in the Output array as return argument. Because of scope level, I am getting the last value.

Right now I am able to return one the last value because of the scope issue.

```
public  static String[] getMBeanAppsStatus(String host, String port, 
                                          String container, String filter, 
                                          String usr, String pwd) {
    String Output[] = new String[3];
    int mbeanAppsIdx = 0;
    int LVar = mbeanAppsIdx;
    try {
        Object[] connections = 
            connectMethd(host, port, container, filter, usr, pwd);

        MBeanServerConnection serverConn = 
            (MBeanServerConnection)connections[0];
        System.out.println("serverConn from array variable in getMBeanAppsStatus" + 
                           serverConn);
        /* retrieve mbean apps matching given filter */
        ObjectName mbeanDomainName = new ObjectName(filter);
        Set mbeanAppNames = serverConn.queryNames(mbeanDomainName, null);
        /* pattern to extract mbean application names */
        Pattern mbeanAppPat = 
            Pattern.compile("name=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        /* mbean application name */
        ObjectName mbeanApp = null;

        /* retrieve mbean apps count */
        Iterator i;
        for (i = mbeanAppNames.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            mbeanAppsIdx++;
            System.out.println("Populating MBean App #" + mbeanAppsIdx + 
                               "details...");
            /* retrieve mbean app name and status */
            mbeanApp = (ObjectName)i.next();
            String mbeanAppFQDN = mbeanApp.toString();
            String mbeanAppName = mbeanAppPat.split(mbeanAppFQDN)[1];
            Boolean mbeanAppRunning = 
                Boolean.valueOf(serverConn.getAttribute(mbeanApp, 
                                                        "Running").toString());
            String mbeanAppStatus = "DISABLED";
            if (mbeanAppRunning.booleanValue())
                mbeanAppStatus = "ENABLED";
            Output[0] = mbeanAppName;
            Output[1] = mbeanAppFQDN;
            Output[2] = mbeanAppStatus;
            System.out.println("getMBeanAppsStatus output " + 
                               "mbeanAppName " + mbeanAppName + 
                               " mbeanAppFQDN " + mbeanAppFQDN + 
                               " mbeanAppStatus : " + mbeanAppStatus);

        }

    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (InstanceNotFoundException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (AttributeNotFoundException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (ReflectionException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (MBeanException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }

    System.out.println("getMBeanAppsStatus Output " + Output);
    return Output;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to convert the above method to a J2EE webservice and the response from the web service will be a return value of  Output from the method.

I have 2 issues here in method which i want to rectify it.

1) Want to concatenate the value of `mbeanAppName`, `mbeanAppFQDN` and `mbeanAppStatus` with comma `,`  separator and assign to array variable.

2) Return the array result  which should hold all the previous values also.

Comment: Could you show a sample output?

Comment: Thanks for the response... Here the sample output Populating MBean App #63details...
getMBeanAppsStatus output mbeanAppName Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean mbeanAppFQDN default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean mbeanAppStatus : DISABLED
So from the output the last Mbean is 63rd one, but all the previous value were overwritten by the next output

Comment: You are only seeing the 63rd output because at each iteration, you are overwriting the previous output with the current one. Are you trying to store all the 63 outputs in the String array Output?

Comment: no i am not.. Infact i dont know how to store and pass it in return. Sorry novice  in Java... if you can guide me how to do.. it would be great help.. current my webservice return the values as below            <ns0:getMBeanAppsStatusResponseElement>
   <ns0:result>Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean</ns0:result>
   <ns0:result>default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean</ns0:result>
   <ns0:result>DISABLED</ns0:result>
  </ns0:getMBeanAppsStatusResponseElement>

Comment: How would you like the output to be displayed? Give me an example. As you are a novice in Java, you should begin with JavaSE instead of jumping straight into JavaEE. Learning JavaSE with teach you the majority of things you need to know about Java. Then, You will be better equipped to tackle JavaEE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. i will start learning JaveSE and the above requirement is specific to project and i am into Middleware so at this point of time i need to implement it.. I want the out as below if there is more then one Mbean<ns0:getMBeanAppsStatusResponseElement><ns0:result>Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean,default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean,DISABLED</ns0:result> <ns0:result>Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean1,default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean1,DISABLED</ns0:result>
   <ns0:result>DISABLED</ns0:result>
  </ns0:getMBeanAppsStatusResponseElement>

Regards TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only seeing the last ouput because at each iteration, you are overwritting the previous output with the current one.

1. You can use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate `mbeanAppName`, `mbeanAppFQDN` and `mbeanAppStatus` separated by a comma `,`. This can be accomplished in the following way:

   ```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      /* Declare and initialise variables somewhere in between*/

      sb.append(mbeanAppName);
      sb.append(",");
      sb.append(mbeanAppFQDN);
      sb.append(",");
      sb.append(mbeanAppStatus);

      String generatedStringOutputFromStringBuilder = sb.toString();
   ```
2. You can use a `List` to store the output after each iteration. Unlike an array, a `List` can change size. You don't have to declare its when when you initialise it. Add the output to the created `List` at each iteration. For example:

   ```
      List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

      /* Declare and initialise variables somewhere in between*/

      output.add(generatedStringOutputFromStringBuilder);
   ```

Here is the corrected sample that should set you in the right direction.

```
public  static List<String> getMBeanAppsStatus(String host, String port, 
                                          String container, String filter, 
                                          String usr, String pwd) {
    // A new List
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    //A StringBuilder that will be used to build each ouput String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int mbeanAppsIdx = 0;
    int LVar = mbeanAppsIdx;
    try {
        Object[] connections = connectMethd(host, port, container, filter, usr, pwd);

        MBeanServerConnection serverConn = (MBeanServerConnection)connections[0];

        System.out.println("serverConn from array variable in getMBeanAppsStatus" + serverConn);

        /* retrieve mbean apps matching given filter */
        ObjectName mbeanDomainName = new ObjectName(filter);
        Set mbeanAppNames = serverConn.queryNames(mbeanDomainName, null);

        /* pattern to extract mbean application names */
        Pattern mbeanAppPat = Pattern.compile("name=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        /* mbean application name */
        ObjectName mbeanApp = null;

        /* retrieve mbean apps count */
        Iterator i;
        for (i = mbeanAppNames.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

            mbeanAppsIdx++;
            System.out.println("Populating MBean App #" + mbeanAppsIdx + "details...");

            /* retrieve mbean app name and status */
            mbeanApp = (ObjectName)i.next();

            String mbeanAppFQDN = mbeanApp.toString();
            String mbeanAppName = mbeanAppPat.split(mbeanAppFQDN)[1];
            Boolean mbeanAppRunning = Boolean.valueOf(serverConn.getAttribute(mbeanApp, "Running").toString());
            String mbeanAppStatus = "DISABLED";

            if (mbeanAppRunning.booleanValue())
                mbeanAppStatus = "ENABLED";

            // Construct the output using a string builder as
            //      mbeanAppName,mbeanAppFQDN,mbeanAppStatus
            sb.append(mbeanAppName);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(mbeanAppFQDN);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(mbeanAppStatus);

            // Store the current ouput in the List output
            output.add(sb.toString());

            // Empty string builder
            sb.setLength(0)

            System.out.println("getMBeanAppsStatus output " + 
                               "mbeanAppName " + mbeanAppName + 
                               " mbeanAppFQDN " + mbeanAppFQDN + 
                               " mbeanAppStatus : " + mbeanAppStatus);

        }

    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (InstanceNotFoundException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (AttributeNotFoundException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (ReflectionException e) {

        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (MBeanException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }

    System.out.println("getMBeanAppsStatus Output " + output);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Jean, Thanks a lot .. Your solution worked... I have one more regarding out... Is it possible get the out 3 variable. like Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean
default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean
DISABLED
======
Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean1
default:type=Application,name=Aramex_TEST_SOStatusMBean1
DISABLED

If there are 2 MBean it should return like above values and each should hold in one variable. Is it possible in java??